# How to display NextGEN gallery in templates?

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I have installed the NextGEN Gallery plugin and have all my images in albums. Can someone please support me in displaying the NextGEN gallery with the use of the [Galleryview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-galleryview2/) plugin?

Is there any easier way?

Comment: you can add shortcode of Nextgen Gallery in template using do_shortcode function of wordpress. Link :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 1):

With both Nextgen Gallery and Nextgen-Galleryview active, the shortcode `[nggallery id=1 template="galleryview"]` should work with **`1`** being your gallery ID.

Comment: Hi, ellen, are you sure the shortcode will work with the mentioned plugin? (Galleryview)

Comment: @brasofilo Yep, it works with TwentyTwelve [link](http://nextgen.ellenjanemoore.com/nextgen-galleryview/)

Comment: Sorry, ellen, misread your Answer, it's stated there...

Answer (score 0):

```
// How to fetch NextGEN Gallery by custom query    
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures 
    WHERE gid=3 AND wp_ngg_pictures.gid='wp_ngg_pictures'.galleryid ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlquery );
if ( $pageposts ) {
    global $post;
    foreach ( $pageposts as $post ) { 
        ?><img src="<?php echo $post->path; ?>/<?php echo $post->filename; ?>" alt=""><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code